# Segmentation fault in creating Linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

In this particular question I am trying to find the segmentation fault which is occurring. I know there is an error while creating a linked list of individual digits of K.

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;
int k = 1;

int calc(Node *h)
{
    int sum=0;
    for( ; h != NULL ; h = h->next)
        sum=(sum*10)+h->data;
    return sum;
}

Node* Lists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
{
    n1 = calc(headA);
    n2 = calc(headB);
    int k = n1 + n2;
    Node *temp;
    temp->data=k%10;

    while(k>0)
    {
        k=k/10;
        Node *t1=new Node;
        t1->data=k%10;
        t1->next=temp;
        temp=t1;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: You tried to assign a value to `temp->data` without allocating a space for it. `Node *temp` is a pointer and therefore needs allocated memory before assignment.

Comment: For all values, where `n1+n2` is less than `10`, you'll wind up with a leading zero digit, i.e. your head node will have a `data` value of `0`. For all values, where `n1+n2` is less than `0`, it is implementation-defined, whether the digits have a sign (prior to C++11, see [Multiplicative operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators)).

Answer (score 0):

The error resides in the following code:

```
Node *temp;
temp->data = k % 10;
```

Specifically, `temp` is declared to be a pointer that points to a `Node` struct, but it is **never given a valid location in memory** to point to, so it contains a garbage address that most likely refers to some non-writeable region.

If you wanted to fix this, you would first allocate a region for your variable, like this:

```
Node *temp = new Node;
```

and then mark it as released (by calling `delete` on it) later on when you were done with it. I would also recommend better formatting your code, as it's not exactly convenient to read from the viewer's perspective.